# Versioning for ContentPart's without a record

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to create draftable versions of content parts that have no record.

For example

```
public MyContentPart : ContentPart
{
...
}
```

When I create a draftable version of `MyContentPart` it doesn't behave the same as a part that inherits from `ContentPart<MyContentPartVersionRecord>` would. E.g. change some values of it's properties and still see the original values in the last published version.

Comment: What did you try? If you store the data on the infoset, in theory it should be versioned.

Comment: That's what I thought, however if you get a draft item from the content manager using `_contentManager.GetDraftRequired(..)` then change some values in the part. The values will also change in the latest published version of the part as well. I've experimented fairly extensively and it's just not working the same as a part with a versioned backing record.

Comment: Did you mark the content type as draftable?